# (SMD model) How to prevent stretchy textures when model is animated?

Tags: animation, texturing, armature, export

***What I am trying to do:***

Import a model from blender into Garry's Mod (a video game). I applied a basic skeleton with the proper format needed to port a model into the game:

When I fixed the model to port into the game, I used a strict skeleton implemented in most player models in the game, so the armature for the model is not custom and I was forced to copy and paste to maintain the games format.

[image]

The model looks fine in a 't-pose', the pose it was rigged on in blender, the one pictured above or, in game, below:

[image]

When the model attempts to run animations like holding a weapon, the textures stretch:

[image]

Comment: IDK what you mean by “forced to copy and paste to retain the game format.” I’ve imported models like this before. I suspect this is the cause of the mesh stretching problem. Can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: So versus using rigify or mixamo to rig my model, I copy and paste a skeleton from one of the working player models in the game and rig it to that so I dont have to worry about animations/formatting verticies/and rigging bones myself. I simply transform the object (my model) in edit mode to fit the bone structure and it ports just fine.

Comment: I could custom rig animations but the problem is the server I plan to implement this into usually ports with the basic animations, so it would not fit their format: I am constrained to not being able to create new animations or custom rig my model.

Comment: So… this skeleton was not meant for this model?